# Difference between Mini-ITX and thin Mini-ITX

Tags: motherboard, mini-itx, form-factor

Recently, I've noticed a new type of motherboard form factor: **Thin Mini-ITX**.

I've tried to find specification of it, but couldn't find any useful info. Wikipedia page about Mini-ITX doesn't have any references to it.

So, what is the difference between old known **Mini-ITX** and new **Thin Mini-ITX**? Is there a some new standard behind it or it's just some marketing ploy?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's an older version of the spec that's available at Intel.com: [Thin Mini-ITX spec 1.2](http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/product-specifications/thin-mini-itx-based-pc-system-design-guide-rev-1-2.pdf). The fundamental differences are:

1. Z-height restrictions on the I/O shield.
2. SODIMM instead of traditional UDIMM memory
3. On-board power-supply adapter, so you use an external brick power supply.
4. Locked CPU location. Many chassis have custom thermal solutions, so a locked CPU location still enables choice of motherboard.
5. Zoned I/O ports. This is more difficult to explain but due to the space constraints of an AIO, the wires can't have too much slack. Again, most USB ports, case fans, etc. are only deployed into certain zones to ensure interoperability between any chassis.
6. LVDS and some eDP support. Enables internal video. If your system has an integrated panel (AIO), you don't have to run a cable out of the board back into the panel.

Answer (score 8):

Intel created this form factor, primarily aimed at being used in All-In-One PCs.

The easiest explanation is that they are thinner than regular Mini-ITX boards.  Single stack ports on the back (I/O Shield height), (lay-flat) notebook-style memory sockets, etc.

> Thin Mini-ITX desktop boards have a lower z-height to support more compact All-in-One PC designs.

[image]

[Source](https://www-ssl.intel.com/content/www/us/en/hardware-developers/thin-mini-itx-detail.html)

More info:

- http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/hardware-developers/aio-thin-mini-itx-desktop.html
- http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/hardware-developers/thin-mini-itx-desktop-boards.html

Comment: Thanks! It makes sense. But is there a standard behind this or it's loosely specified? I mean what are the concrete requirements for MB to be regarded as Thin or not Thin?

Comment: It's not a fully documented form factor yet, as far as I can find.